# Extract Reading Order Sequence in a Tagged PDF

Tags: java, c#, pdf, accessibility, acrobat

I'm currently validating the correct order of the content in a Tagged PDF File.

Is there any way to extract the reading order numbers of Tagged PDF Files programmatically?

[image: Image Sample]

I've tried converting the tagged PDF to XML but I can't figure out which tags belong to a certain text.

I've tried the following Libraries:

- Syncfusion
- IText7

but I can't find any methods that get its reading order numbers.

Is it really possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the reading order given by the structure tree? Then all you have to do is extract the text along the structure tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the marked content tree of tagged pdf using the [PdfPig](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig) (.NET) library. My understanding is that the reading order is indicated by the Marked-content identifier (MCID).

If a marked content element does not contain an MCID (like pagination elements), the MCID is set to -1.

Each `MarkedContentElement` will contain the letters, images and paths that belong to it:

```
        using UglyToad.PdfPig;
        [...]

        using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open(pathToFile))
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < document.NumberOfPages; p++)
            {
                var page = document.GetPage(p + 1);

                // extract the page's marked content
                var markedContents = page.GetMarkedContents(); 

                var orderedMarkedContents = markedContents
                       .OrderBy(mc => mc.MarkedContentIdentifier);

                foreach (var mc in orderedMarkedContents)
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

If you want to extract the result to XML, you can have a look at the `PageXmlTextExporter` class. Have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki/Document-Layout-Analysis) for more information on `ITextExporter` and `IReadingOrderDetector`.

Note: I am an active contributer to this library.

Comment: The MCID merely is an ID. It *often* parallels the reading order because usually the MCIDs on a page are generated incrementally for text elements processed in reading order. But there is nothing that *requires* this. One can easily create a PDF for which the MCIDs imply a completely wrong order.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for the clarification. So you would rely only on the tree structure to determine the reading order?

Comment: Yes, the logical structure order is defined by a depth-first traversal of the page’s logical structure hierarchy.